# Massively multilingual Euro crossword

Tags: knowledge, language, crosswords

[image]

The clues in this crossword are in 18 different European languages: English, Belarusian, Catalan, Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, Finnish, French, German, Greek, Hungarian, Italian, Portuguese, Romanian, Russian, Spanish and Swedish. Each language is used in one "across" clue and one "down" clue. Write each answer in the same language as the clue, using that language's proper script – no transliteration is necessary. (This means some crossing letters will need to be interpreted as similar-looking letters from another script.) Remove any diacritical marks and write digraphs as two separate letters in the grid.

**Across**
1. For example, pre- or -less
5. Bringe til verden
11. Britischer Gitarrist und Sänger, Mark
12. Samverkan
14. Fiore esotico
15. Часціцы ў фізіцы
16. "Rudý" vikingský mořeplavec
17. Человек занимающийся торговлей
19. Alakuloinen
20. Entitat financera
22. Praticante feminina de desporto de combate
26. Zbirka staronordijskih tekstova
27. Serie (de ex. de lecții)
30. Justo, verdadero
31. Γυναίκα από νησί της Αυστραλίας
32. Relatif à la mer
33. A Nap felkelésének iránya
34. Dat wat je wint in een loterij

**Down**
1. Maa Uralin takana
2. Utilidade; ação própria
3. Kyčelník
4. Fysisk eller verbalt overfald
6. Піваварны завод ў Мінску
7. Kontinens
8. Character portrayed by Wesley Snipes
9. Flotte espagnole "invincible"
10. Παραδείγματος χάριν, Τζούλιαν Ασάνζ
13. Lidstaat van de Europese Unie
18. Non troppo cotti (2,5)
20. Число планет в Солнечной системе
21. Indómito, salvaje
23. Saltea japoneză
24. Tihi, Atlantski i Indijski
25. Manament d’una autoritat
28. Zu jeder Zeit
29. Fristående förråd eller garage

Comment: The Greek horizontal clue (31. Γυναίκα από το νησί της Αυστραλίας) translates to "Woman from **the** island of Australia. It would be more correct to have it as "Γυναίκα από νησί της Αυσταλίας" or "Γυναίκα από ένα νησί της Αυστραλίας", which would translate to, "Woman from **an** island of Australia".

Comment: @hb20007 Fixed, thanks! Out of all the languages here Greek is the least familiar to me. Glad it still turned out to be solvable even with that error.

Comment: I interpreted it hb20007's way at first, but it pretty quickly became obvious what the answer had to be :-). (For the avoidance of doubt, this doesn't mean I interpreted it hb20007's way because of my superior knowledge of Greek, I just guessed the right/wrong way.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grid:

> [image]

Answers and languages:

Across

> 1. en AFFIX For example, pre- or -less
> 5. da SKABE Bringe til verden
> 11. de KNOPFLER Britischer Gitarrist und Sänger, Mark
> 12. sv SYNERGI Samverkan
> 14. it ORCHIDEA Fiore esotico
> 15. be ATAMI Часціцы ў фізіцы
> 16. cs ERIK "Rudý" vikingský mořeplavec
> 17. ru продавец Человек занимающийся торговлей
> 19. fi APEA Alakuloinen
> 20. ca BANC Entitat financera
> 23. pt LUTADORA Praticante feminina de desporto de combate
> 26. hr EDDA Zbirka staronordijskih tekstova
> 27. ro CICLU Serie (de ex. de lecții)
> 30. es CORRECTO Justo, verdadero
> 31. tr TASMANI Γυναίκα από το νησί της Αυστραλίας
> 32. fr MARITIME Relatif à la mer
> 33. hu KELET A Nap felkelésének iránya
> 34. nl PRIJS Dat wat je wint in een loterij

Down

> 1. fi AASIA Maa Uralin takana
> 2. pt FUNCAO Utilidade; ação própria
> 3. cs ILEUM Kyčelník
> 4. da ANGREB Fysisk eller verbalt overfald
> 6. be Крыніца Піваварны завод ў Мінску
> 7. hu AFRIK Kontinens
> 8. en BLADE Character portrayed by Wesley Snipes
> 9. fr ARMADA Flotte espagnole "invincible"
> 10. gr AUSTRALOS Παραδείγματος χάριν, Τζούλιαν Ασάνζ
> 13. nl NEDERLAND Lidstaat van de Europese Unie
> 18. it AL DENTE Non troppo cotti (2,5)
> 20. ru BOCECMb Число планет в Солнечной системе
> 21. es CERRIL Indómito, salvaje
> 23. ro TATAMI Saltea japoneză
> 24. hr OCEANI Tihi, Atlantski i Indijski
> 25. ca ORDRE Manament d’una autoritat
> 28. de IMMER Zu jeder Zeit
> 29. sv UTHUS Fristående förråd eller garage

Note on answers above:

> I haven't given *explanations* as for most crosswords because this isn't a cryptic crossword; the definitions are just definitions. In most cases I have represented letters by Roman equivalents, and have been a bit sloppy about whether I've used ones with the same *sound* or ones with the same *appearance*; sorry. For the Cyrillic ones I have mostly used actual Cyrillic letters, but they are mostly lowercase unlike the capitals elsewhere; sorry again.

Comment: All correct, nice job! For reference, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejzaA.png) is the filled grid with the appropriate non-Latin characters.

Comment: In Garetch's grid, 25 down has very many consonants in a row, and it isn't even in Czech :-)

Comment: Oh, oops. First letter of that one should be an O. Also, I'm not sure why the numbers have all disappeared. I can definitely fix the former; will see whether I can fix the latter.

Comment: Yup, I can. Typo fixed and numbers added. Sorry about that.

Comment: I worked out how to get non-Latin characters into my grid. I have a slight disagreement with Jafe about one letter of the brewery name; I'm going on the basis of what they have on their website.